# NuxtJS and Composition API - function not found

Tags: vuejs3, gsap, nuxtjs3

I have a simple NuxtJS project and my goal is add pageTransition with gsap when user enter and leave a page.

I have 2 pages, `index.vue` and `about.vue`.

Here is the index.vue page ( where onEnter and onLeave animation takes places. )

```
<script setup>
import gsap from 'gsap'

definePageMeta({
    layout: "landing",
    pageTransition: {
        name: 'page-transiton',
        mode: 'out-in',
        onEnter: (el, done) => {                
            animateHero();
            done();
        },
        onLeave: (el, done) => {
            gsap
                .timeline({ paused: true, onComplete: done })
                .to("#main-logo-text", {
                    delay: 0.2,
                    duration: 0.3,
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    y: '-100%'
                })
                .to("#landing .hero-content .hero-title", {
                    duration: 0.25,
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    y: -50
                })
                .to("#landing .contact-info", {
                    duration: 0.25,
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    y: -50
                })
                .to("#landing .hero-content .hero-link", {
                    duration: 0.25,
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    y: -50
                })
                .play();
        },
    },
});

useHead({
    title: 'Home',
    meta: [
        { name: 'description', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' }
    ]
})

function animateHero() {
    gsap
        .timeline()
        .to("#main-logo-text", {
            delay: 0.2,
            duration: 0.3,
            autoAlpha: 1,
            y: 0
        })
        .to("#landing .hero-content .hero-title", {
            duration: 0.25,
            autoAlpha: 1,
            y: 0
        })
        .to("#landing .contact-info", {
            duration: 0.25,
            autoAlpha: 1,
            y: 0
        })
        .to("#landing .hero-content .hero-link", {
            duration: 0.25,
            autoAlpha: 1,
            y: 0
        });
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <LogoPreloader @complete="animateHero"/>
        <section id="landing" class="full-width">
            <div class="container p-0">
                <div class="row min-height align-items-center">
                    <Hero />
                    <ContactInfo />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "~/assets/sass/config";
@import "~/assets/sass/mixins";

#landing {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: calc(100vw - 170px);
    padding-left: 70px !important;
}
</style>
```

As you can see there is `@complete` event that run `animateHero` and it works.
When user came back to the home, the `onEnter` function defined in `definePageMeta` should be called, but I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: animateHero is not defined
```

What am I missing?